# Notepad++ regex backreference doesn't seem to work

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need to add **;** at the end of every line that does not end with `:`, `{`, `}` or `)`.

I'm using this in Notepad++:

- Search for: `[^:\{\}\)]$`
- Replace with: `\1;`

It finds the strings all right but it replaces the last character found before the end of line with `;` instead of adding it to it. I tried `$1` instead of `\1`  but it didn't change anything — the found text still gets deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your pattern has no capturing group, hence `\1` is an empty string. Use `$0` instead to refer to the whole match:

**Find What**: `[^:{})]$`
**Replace with**: `$0;`

However, it might fail in some edge cases (the `[^:{})]$` pattern matches any char other than `:`, `{`, `}` and `)`, so requires at least 1 char before a line end), perhaps, you should better use a negative lookbehind here:

**Find What**: `$(?<![:{})])`
**Replace with**: `;`

The `$(?<![:{})])` pattern matches the end of line (with `$`) and then the `(?<![:{})])` negative lookbehind makes sure that there is no `:`, `{`, `}` or `)` immediately to the left of the current location.

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting it now! :)